# Using database entries as function parameters

Tags: function, delphi, adoconnection

I am using Delphi to access my pgsql database using the components:

ADOQuery, ADOConnection and DataSource and DBGrid.

I 've seen that it is convenient to present data in a TStringGrid (rather than a DBGrid)so am also using the code below:

```
procedure TForm2.StringGrid1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x,y: integer;
begin
  StringGrid1.ColCount := DBGrid1.Columns.Count;
  StringGrid1.RowCount := DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecordCount+1;
  StringGrid1.FixedCols := 0;
  for y := 0 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count-1 do
    StringGrid1.Cells[y, 0] := DBGrid1.Columns[y].Title.Caption;
  x := 1;
  DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.DisableControls;
  DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.First;

  while not DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Eof do
  begin
    for y := 0 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count-1 do
      StringGrid1.Cells[y,x] :=                                
        DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(DBGrid1.Columns[y].FieldName).AsString;
    inc(x);
    DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Next;
  end;
  DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.EnableControls;
end;
```

The database has 2 columns of G and T data respectively.
Now, in a different project, I have made a number of functions setting G,T parametres as indicated below:

```
 function FindSomething(G, T:double):double;
```

What I am asking is how can I use as G, T parametres, for my function, the cell entries from the above database columns? I am very new at this and it's been very tricky all the way. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You have to read the contents of the cell, and convert it to a double using `StrToFloat`. (If you were doing it properly and using TDBGrid, you could just use the field's `AsFloat` property instead, but with the TStringGrid there's no connection between the data and the grid, so it won't work.)

Comment: This code looks like it'll work for two records, but more than two looks like it won't work. You need two nested loops for row and column, not one for columns while you increment the row count inside of that loop. But what Ken says is correct. My only question is, are G and T actually doubles? Or are they integers corresponding to row/column positions? It's unclear if your search is for the cell (row/column) containing a value, or a value in a given cell.

Comment: I see, thank you both. Well, G, T are doubles and are values that I need to put into my function. Do you think the best way is to put my columns into two-dimensional arrays of doubles instead and work my function from there? I thought about it and it seemed more reasonable.